# Dual Boot SteamOS from VHD

Tags: linux, multi-boot, windows-8.1, boot-to-vhd, steam-os

I have a Windows 8.1 machine.

I made a SteamOS Virtual Machine on HyperV, using the [Ye Old SteamOS ISO](http://directhex.github.io/steamos-installer/)

I know it's possible to dual boot from VHD, however Windows bootloader does not support non windows / Linux VHD boot, and SteamOS is a Debian. I wonder if it's possible to dual boot this SteamOS VHD and if it is, how will I do it?

Comment: Here is a similar question with a possible answer: http://superuser.com/questions/33535/can-i-boot-linux-from-a-vhd

Comment: That's more than 4 years old, vmlite has no update since.

Comment: There are other answers to that question.